# For what integer $n$ is $1+n$ divisible by $1+n^2$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

For what integer $n$ is $1+n$ divisible by $1+n^2$?

I tried it in modulo $3$ and $8$ but to no avail.

Trial and error gave me answers $0$,$1$,$-2$ and $-3$.

Comment: Modulo $n+1$, $n^2=1$, so $1$ is a solution and is the only positive one, since $n+1>2$ as long as $n>1$.

Comment: @mrnovice No bro! I didn't mean that.

Comment: "$1+n$ divisible by $1+n^2$" or "$1+n^2$ divisible by $1+n$" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you mean $n^2+1$ is divisible by $n+1$, we have:

$$n^2+1=(n^2-1)+2= (n-1)(n+1)+2$$
We know that $(n-1)(n+1)$ is divisible by $n+1$, and the problem states that $n^2+1$ is also divisible by $n+1$, thus $n+1$ divides their difference $(n^2+1)-(n^2-1)=2$. So acceptable values for $n+1$ are $1$, $2$, $-1$, $-2$, thus $n=0, 1, -2, -3$ are all integer solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 7):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{n^2+1}{n+1}=\dfrac{(n+1-1)^2+1}{n+1}=n+1-2+\dfrac2{n+1}$$

OR

$$\dfrac{n^2+1}{n+1}=\dfrac{(n+1)(n-1)+2}{n+1}=n-1+\dfrac2{n+1}$$

Comment: Quite interesting that $n=-3$ is a solution.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, Clearly $-3+1$ divides $2$

Comment: You mean $10$ instead of $2$.

Comment: @Michael Hoppe $2 = 1\cdot (-3+1) \Rightarrow \frac{2}{-3+1} \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow n-1+\frac{2}{n+1} \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow n+1|n^{2}+1$

Answer (score -2):

The only solutions are 0 and 1

Comment: Nope. $-3$ is also a solution.

Comment: in what sense is -2 divisible by 10? Besides where -2 and 10 are 0 or 1 in module arithmetic